# Local to live server

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, input, xampp

I developed a website on an XAMPP local server. One of my functions takes user input inside of a text field and returns data to the document from a database through a LIKE query as the user types; through a ‘keyup’ event in JavaScript.

Example: a user types in ‘a’ into the text field and ‘apple, asparagus, apricot’ gets returned in div boxes on the side of the page. If the user types ‘p’ after typing ‘a’, ‘apple’ and ‘apricot’ show up (narrowing search results).

On my local server this is smooth and the user can type as many letters and spaces and gets results without issue. On my goDaddy live server, the page ends up freezing after so many user input characters.

Why is this?

Is there a way to test functions like this through a local server so I don’t spend hours developing a website that doesn’t function properly through a live server?

Comment: Well, the browser is trying to connect to the server in the background as soon as the `keyup` event is triggered, so you're pretty much overloading the page with events and XHRs because that event is being triggered a lot. Fire your browser's developer tools and look at the network tab to see what's going on with your site when you use it. On a local server, the connection is pretty much instant, therefore there aren't many AJAX tasks running at the same time, but otherwise, it depends on your internet connection and hardware resources.

Comment: When I check the network tab it shows requests for every letter. Eventually the input ends up freezing the entire page. However, I've seen websites do this before with no issue. Would it be wise to put all of the items that the user can query inside of a JSON file instead of a database? Like one big object of strings the user can search from?

Comment: Not exactly, because keep in mind that the searching feature is running on your server, not the browser. So that shouldn't be an issue at all unless the server can't handle the tasks, but that's highly unlikely. If the browser/site freezes, it's definitely happening on the client-side. Actually, your approach is very common and I use it a lot. Have you tried accessing through another computer or browser? Also, try typing slower and let the browser complete each request to see if it still freezes after a while. It's a weird behavior because any computer should be able to handle this with ease.

Comment: I mean... you can always tweak your code, improve it and make it faster, more efficient, all of that can help. I haven't seen your code nor do I know your computer's and server's specs, but I can't imagine this task doing that on an average consumer PC, that's why I think it needs testing before changing anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses @Zeke. I've tried it from several computers and have had friends log in and try it and their browser will freeze up as well when they use it. I'll try some different approaches and see if it makes things any better. I wonder if I can save all of the search results in an object and just have the user interact with that object if it will help the network flush.

Comment: If at the point in my development career where I'm trying to learn the best coding approach for certain tasks (speed, better user performance). I've been coding for years; I've just never really looked at how the network behaves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186827/discussion-between-zeke-and-rob).